# sonar shows Method may fail to clean up stream or resource on checked exception

Tags: java

```
public boolean isAuditTrailEnabled(String masterAccessId) 
{
    String selectQuery = "select t.audit_flag from PARAMETER_MENU_ATTRIBUTES t where t.access_id = '"+masterAccessId+"'";
    PreparedStatement preparedStmnt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String flag = "N";

        if(connection == null)
        {
            initConnection();
        }   
        try {
            **preparedStmnt = connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);**
            resultSet = preparedStmnt.executeQuery();
            if(resultSet.next())
            {
                flag = resultSet.getString(1);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

            try {
                if (resultSet != null){
                    resultSet.close();
                }
                if (preparedStmnt != null){
                    preparedStmnt.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException e1) {

            }

            return true;
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if (resultSet != null){
                    resultSet.close();
                }
                if (preparedStmnt != null){
                    preparedStmnt.close();
                }
                cleanup();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                return false;
            }

        }
        if(flag.equals("N")){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

}
```

It shows problem at that particular statement. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

always the result set and statement should be closed in separate try catches...and even 2 if connot be written in that way...either its should be looped with in first if...or keep else if....go through basics if condition first

```
if(something)
   {
      if(something)
    }
or

if((something) &&(something))
```